# Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:23.2.0 with compile 'com.thefinestartist:finestwebview:1.2.1'

Tags: android, android-webview, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-appcompat

I'm trying to use this (compile 'com.thefinestartist:finestwebview:1.2.1') library , when I add this in gradle and try to sync I get this error stament:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0
```

[image]

Comment: add complete `build.gradle`

Comment: Try to update your SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **have to update** the SDK Manager.

[image]